# Making a JavaScript code works with any element

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

```
document.getElementById("but").onclick = showDropDown;

function showDropDown(e) {
    document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {};
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); // W3C model
    else e.cancelBubble = true; // IE model
    document.getElementById("window").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.onclick = function(e) {
        var ele = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        if (ele == document.getElementById("but")) {
            hideDropDown();
            return;
        }
        do {
            if (ele == document.getElementById("window")) return;
        } while (ele = ele.parentNode);
        hideDropDown();
    };
}

function hideDropDown() {
    document.onclick = function() {};
    document.getElementById("window").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("but").onclick = showDropDown;
}​


<input id="but" type="button" value="pressMe" />
<div id="window" style="display:none">popup</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nazym/

I was trying to make the JavaScript code dynamic using variables instead of the specified elements' names but I could not. It always returns errors. I want to link it with different elements.

**update**
I want to replace the `id`s of the elements in the JavaScript code with variables so I can use it with any element.I tried to do it but failed. Basically, I want to use variables instead of the `id`s of the element and link it to the elements somehow again.

Comment: Why do you mean by *dynamic*? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I think what he wants to do is to attach click handlers more than `#but` element.

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: You have to identify elements somehow, if you want to use variables for the IDs, then you need a scheme to assign an id to the variable. You can pass them as arguments, or put them in an object or array and pass that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arguments instead:

```
function showDropDown(element, e) {

    element.onclick = function() {};

    // ....

    hideDropDown(element);

}
```

And you would give the element it's onclick event handler like this:

```
document.getElementById('but').onclick = function(event) {
    showDropDown(this, event);
};
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/xNSZm/

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3rct18cumwva7m/bar3.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzeiq6043rvueqf/Capture.PNG  
there is a syntax error with the code. In the demo it's working but it's buggy.

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi That's correct. jsFiddle adds an invisible character to the end of the JavaScript input. If you still need the code with the character taken out, here it is -- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1168447/

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
var showDropdown = function(e) { ... };
document.getElementById("but").onclick = showDropDown;
```

In other words, store the function in a variable before assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> document.onclick = function(e){
```

In browsers that support the IE event model, `e` will be undefined. To accommodate those browsers, you can use:

```
    e = e || window.event;
```

To find the element that was clicked on, instead of:

```
>   var ele = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
```

you can do:

```
    var ele = e.target || e.srcElement;
```

which will work in very many more browsers than *elementFromPoint* so should be more reliable and faster.